# maven download all artifacts by groupid, artifactid and version

Tags: maven

I need to use the `mvn` utility in the cli to download all the artifacts for the known groupid, artifactid and version.
For the specified groupid, artifactid, and version parameters, there can be artifacts with different classifiers.
Could you tell me, please, how to do it?